# Clickable JQuery Tooltip content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to show JQuery tooltip on image mouse over and the content inside the tooltip should be clickable also. But currently the tooltip goes off once the cursor is away.

The below is the code that i currently use

```js
$(".divPreviewPopup").tooltip({
  position: {
    my: "left+15 center",
    at: "right center",
    using: function(position, feedback) {
      $(this).css(position);
      $("<div>")
        .addClass("arrow")
        .addClass(feedback.vertical)
        .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
        .appendTo(this);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add html and css to make a [mcve]

Comment: That's a deviation from what a tooltip is intended to be. Use popovers or modals instead. Also keep in mind that hover isn't viable on mobile.